# Creating a Connection Pool without using a Java EE Application Server

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc, connection-pooling, response-time

I'm building a response-time critical multithreaded application in JSE v7 and I need/want to access an SQL Database (via JDBC) with optimal response time - the application is written using JSE for the most part and I want to ideally avoid putting the critical workload through it sat on an App Server.  Can I achieve Connection Pooling without a Java EE Application Server or is this the only option?

I have three tables I want to Read, two to update and one to insert.

The desired response time is sub 500ms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In no particular order, you might use [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP), [BoneCP](http://jolbox.com/), or [c3p0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/) or Apache [DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/). You may also find [these benchmarks](http://jolbox.com/benchmarks.html) helpful (I would take them with a grain of salt).

[image: Praid Salt Mine - The chapel from the saline - Romania]

Comment: I would like to refer you to [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP). Disclaimer: I am one of the authors.